# rails database advice on adding family members to accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I'm not to rails and I have a website that allows people to create accounts and to register for tournaments.  I want the users to be able to add their minor children to their account.  My original thought was to add the kids to the users table with a parent_id but wanted to get some thoughts on doing that.

I'm trying to add them from the user's show page with a form, but if I creae a form_with(@user... of courseit puls in the current_user's information and edits that accont.

Should I create a minors or kids table then a user_minors table and link them that way or just add the minors table and use a form_tag and specify a different model or something like that.

I hope that makes sense.  If not please let me know and I can edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

A `Parent has_many :children`.

You can use a nested route with this:

```
resources :parents do
  resources :children
end
```

This way, you can create a parent first and after you can add a button (e.g. in the Parents#index), linking to: `/parents/1/children/new` like so:

```
<%= link_to 'Add Child', new_parent_child_path(@parent) %>
```

In your form (e.g. in `app/views/childrens/_form.html.erb`) you create a form like :

```
<%= form_with model: [@parent, @child] do |form| %>
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>

    <%= form.submit%>
<% end %>
```

This will perform a POST to you `ChildrenController#create` (or `#update)` if it's a edit)

where you can do like this:

```
class ChildrenController < ApplicationController
  before_action :parent
  before_action :child, only: %i[create]

  def new
    @child = @parent.children.new
  end

  def create
    if @child.save
      flash[:success] = 'Child was successfully created.'
      redirect_to locations_path
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = @child.errors.full_messages.join('<br />').html_safe
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def parent
    # get your current_user from session controller
    @parent = current_user.parents.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def child
    @child = parent.children.new(child_params)
  end

  def child_params
    params.require(:child).permit(:name)
  end
```